# Udp packet out of order tolerance

Tags: networking, udp, packet-loss

I have message data structure with a sequence number and sending them in a udp packet. Because of udp, messages can be get in wrong order. I will skip this out of order messages in general. But i want to add this a tolerance such as average latency in the network. E.g. Latency=10 seconds. When i get seq=3 5 seconds after seq=4 has arrived. I will assume this a race condition and accept the message with seq=3. I should also drop seq=3 if seq=3 also arrived since there may be retransmissions in my protocol.

Do you prefer better handling scenarios to handle out of order packets caused by race condition in udp? Or are there well known app logics (or protocols) with same behavior?

Must conditions: udp, discarding same seq.

Thanks.

Comment: 'Race condition'? Please explain. The issue here is not the late #3, it is the out of order #4.

Comment: normally i will discard 3 because it is old. But i think if 4-3 comes in a small time difference i think i musnt ignore 3. Maybe i can reorder 4-3 in a reasonable delay but that is not a must.